# framework7 issue with a accordion

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I am using **framework7 last version**, and my app hierarchy is like that :

- vue router-view,
- vue children are loaded within router-view,
- one of those children is the root of framework7 app,

When I navigate between "the root of framework7 which is a component" and any other component, the accordion animation start to stuck and act unexpectedly with no console errors. Other framework7 animations work fine except accordion after navigation. But it works good before navigation is started.

I try to reset everything here with in the `vue` component which acts as root for `framework7` app:

```
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          appIsRdy: false
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.$store.state.f7.f7Obj = new Framework7({
          root: '.f7root'
        });
        this.$store.state.f7.$$ = Dom7;
        this.$store.state.f7.mView = this.$store.state.f7.f7Obj.addView('.view-main', { domCache: true });
        this.appIsRdy = true;
      },
      components: {
        MainPage,
        RedditPage
      },
      beforeDestroy() {
        this.$store.state.f7.f7Obj = null;
        this.$store.state.f7.$$ = null;
        this.$store.state.f7.mView = null;
        this.appIsRdy = false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **2 days** of searching:

I found that when you are working with Framework7 and Vue.js components it is best to avoid using Inline Pages with (DOM Cache) and it is better to use Dynamic Pages.

As I understood from forums and posts that I've read - the problem is fixed by converting **Inline Pages** to **Dynamic Pages**.